# How to get a directory listing from a CLIPS program

Tags: clips

I am trying to find a way to get a directory listing from a running CLIPS program. The end goal is to have my CLIPS program run, find a set of files of facts to load into CLIPS, and then to run my rules.

According to http://www2.cs.siu.edu/~rahimi/cs537/slides/big-2.pdf, I tried

```
(defrule list-the-directory 
=>
  (printout t (system “ls ” “*.txt”) crlf)
)
```

That function call completed without an exception but returned nothing.

Oh, I am running CLIPS 6.3 on Mac OS X.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bernie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLIPS system function calls the C system library function. Any output from the system call is going to be directed to the terminal/console (C standard output). If you're running CLIPS as a terminal/console application, you'll see the output directed to the terminal/console. If you're using the CLIPS IDE, you won't see any output from C standard output because the IDE dialog window is capturing and displaying output directly from CLIPS.

If you direct the output from the system command to a file, you can open the file and print its contents using CLIPS I/O commands:

```
(defrule list-the-directory
   =>
   (system "ls > out.txt")
   (open "out.txt" out "r")
   (bind ?line (readline out))
   (while (neq ?line EOF)
      (printout t ?line crlf)
      (bind ?line (readline out)))
   (close out))
```

If you use the Load Constructs... menu command to load your rules, the directory will be set to the directory containing the rules and you can specify a partial directory path when creating and opening the file. Otherwise, you'll need to specify the full file path.